# Confusing light switches

Tags: wiring, switch, light

HELP! I cannot seem to wrap my head around what’s happening here. You are looking at a two light switch wall terminal. one switch is a three-way light switch with a common and the two traveler wires. The other light switch has two pairs of red and white wires going to it from two different cables.

The switch with the four wires seems to control the porch light, which is **also** controlled from inside the garage by what I assume is in three way switch. The standard three-way switch in the picture controls a switched outlet, which I have not converted to always on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but you do not have a question in your post.  What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @RMDman The implied question is "what is this 4-wire switch doing?"

Answer (score 2):

You are already familiar with a *3-way* light switch. The basic configuration is:

- Hot wire into switch 1
- Two travelers from switch 1 to switch 2
- Switched hot wire from switch 2 to light (or other switched device)
- Neutral starts with the hot and eventually makes its way (there are a couple of different methods) to the light.

Note that I did not mention colors. Colors can be black/white/red (standard cables) or other colors. Which colors are hot, switched hot and travelers? That's anyone's guess. The only guarantee is that neutral will be white (or technically could be gray if you have individual wires, but that's rare).

So in a standard 3-way setup, ignoring grounds, you have 3 wires going to each of two switches.

But what if you want to have more than 2 switches? Then the *middle* switch(es) will have **four wires** in two pairs. One pair from the first 3-way (or another 4-way) and one pair from the second 3-way (or another 4-way). With cables in each pair will be the same 2-out-of-3 of black/white/red (like the red and white in your picture). With individual wires, the wires could be any color (except white, gray, green, yellow/green).

Look for a third switch that controls this light to confirm this. If your goal is to replace this with a new standard switch, any 4-way switch should do fine, but the screw configuration will not necessarily be the same. If your goal is to replace this with a smart switch, the smart switch usually needs to be at the *first* 3-way switch in the series.

Answer (score 0):

The one with 4 wires, should be a 4 way switch.

To control same lighting from three or more locations.

4-way switches are used in combination if you have more than two 3-way switches.